# Symfony2: Persisting entities connected via one-to-one relationship. FK field never set

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I've spent hours on this issue and can't get it to work (new to Symfony2 and Doctrine2).

**Scenario**: I basically have 2 entities in a one-to-one relationship: Customer <-> Address. Just for the record: Customer and Address are using Doctrine's single table inheritance feature. So a Customer is always either a PrivateCustomer or a BusinessCustomer. "Address" is either an InvoiceAddress or a DeliveryAddress etc.... Maybe the problem is related to the STI.

**Problem**: I am using an embedded form for the InvoiceAddress entity within a Customer form so it gets created when a new customer is created. TRednering works fine, but when I am persisting/flushing the customer, a new customer gets created and a new invoice address, BUT the invoiceAddress customer_id is NULL, so the two never get conntected (the FK constraint fails of course). My understanding is that Doctrine will wrap everything in a transaction and automatically assign the customer_id. Am I wrong? It works if I manually persist the invoiceAddress before the customer, but I have the feeling that this should not be necessary.

**Code** (the relevant parts):

InvoiceAddress:

```
namespace Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
* InvoiceAddress
*
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class InvoiceAddress extends Address
{
    /**
    * @var Entity\Customer
    *
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Entity\Customer", inversedBy="invoiceAddress")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="customer_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=FALSE)
    */
    private $customer;

    /**
    * @param Entity\Customer $customer
    */
    public function setCustomer($customer)
    {
        $this->customer = $customer;
    }

    /**
     * @return Entity\Customer
    */
    public function getCustomer()
    {
        return $this->customer;
    }
}
```

Customer:

```
namespace Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

use Entity\User;

/**
 * Customer
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Repository\CustomerRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="customer")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"private" = "Entity\PrivateCustomer", "business" = "Entity\BusinessCustomer"})
 */
class Customer
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

.... OTHER FIELDS ......

/**
 * @var \Entity\InvoiceAddress
 *
 * @Assert\Valid
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Entity\InvoiceAddress", mappedBy="customer", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true, fetch="EAGER")
 */
private $invoiceAddress;

/**
 * @var \Entity\DeliveryAddress
 *
 * @Assert\Valid
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="DeliveryAddress", mappedBy="customer", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true, fetch="LAZY")
 */
private $deliveryAddress;

/**
 * @var \Entity\MarketingAddress
 *
 * @Assert\Valid
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Entity\MarketingAddress", mappedBy="customer", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true, fetch="LAZY")
 */
private $marketingAddress;

/**
 * @var ArrayCollection Entity\Contact
 *
 * @Assert\Valid
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Entity\Contact", mappedBy="customer", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true, fetch="LAZY")
 */
private $contacts;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->contacts = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * @return ArrayCollection
 */
public function getContacts()
{
    return $this->contacts;
}

/**
 * @param Contact $contact
 */
public function addContact(Contact $contact)
{
    if (!$this->contacts->contains($contact)) {
        $this->contacts->add($contact);
        $contact->setCustomer($this);
    }
}

/**
 * @param Contact $contact
 */
public function removeContact(Contact $contact)
{
    if ($this->contacts->contains($contact)) {
        $this->contacts->removeElement($contact);
        $contact->unsetCustomer();
    }
}

/**
 * @param Entity\MarketingAddress $marketingAddress
 */
public function setMarketingAddress($marketingAddress)
{
    $this->marketingAddress = $marketingAddress;
}

/**
 * @return Entity\MarketingAddress
 */
public function getMarketingAddress()
{
    return $this->marketingAddress;
}

/**
 * @param DeliveryAddress $deliveryAddress
 */
public function setDeliveryAddress($deliveryAddress)
{
    $this->deliveryAddress = $deliveryAddress;
}

/**
 * @return Entity\DeliveryAddress
 */
public function getDeliveryAddress()
{
    return $this->deliveryAddress;
}

/**
 * @param Entity\InvoiceAddress $invoiceAddress
 */
public function setInvoiceAddress($invoiceAddress)
{
    $this->invoiceAddress = $invoiceAddress;
}

/**
 * @return Entity\InvoiceAddress
 */
public function getInvoiceAddress()
{
    return $this->invoiceAddress;
}
```

}

The action in CustomerController

```
/**
 * Creates a new PrivateCustomer entity.
 *
 * @Route("/private", name="customer_create_private")
 * @Method("POST")
 * @Template("Customer:private_new.html.twig")
 */
public function createPrivateAction(Request $request)
{
    $customer = new PrivateCustomer();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($customer);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($customer);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('customer_private_edit', array('id' => $customer->getId())));
    }

    return array(
        'entity' => $customer,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
}
```

In the CustomerType I defined the invoiceAddress field like so

```
$builder->add('invoiceAddress', new InvoiceAddressType(), array(
        'label'         => 'Rechnungsadresse',
        'label_render'  => false,
        'widget_form_group_attr' => array(
            'class' => 'form-inline'
        )
    ));
```

**Question**: So do I have to manually do

```
$em->persist($customer->getInvoiceAddress())
$em->persist($customer)
```

just to set the FK. I thought Doctrine's magic should take care of that (because of the CASCADE="persist" option). Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Customer

    public function setInvoiceAddress($invoiceAddress)
    {
        $this->invoiceAddress = $invoiceAddress;
        $invoiceAddress->setCustomer($this); // *** ADD THIS ***
    }
```

It's a very common question.  Just difficult to search for.

Comment: Thanks so much, that did the trick! And you're right: I've read countless posts about cascading, persisting, embedded forms, but I couldn't find an answer to that. Can't believe it is that simple :)